# detection and adding action when app goes to background and comes from background unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to add some actions when app is going to background and when it returns from background. I used OnEnable and OnDisable but did not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are **3** callback functions to do this:

[`OnApplicationFocus`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html), [`OnApplicationPause`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html) and [`OnApplicationQuit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html). They all behave differently and I recommend that you read the linked documentation about each one of them then use the one that suits you.

```
void OnApplicationFocus( bool hasFocus )
{

}

void OnApplicationPause( bool pauseStatus )
{

}

void OnApplicationQuit() 
{

}
```